# Python unittest mocking a class instance variable

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to test my code with python unittest.mock.

Actually, my way of testing was very inspired from this blog post:
http://engineroom.trackmaven.com/blog/real-life-mocking/

Here is a part of the module i want to mock things in it :

```py
class RestRequestManager:
    """
    A Context Manager for class RestRequest.
        This context manager is call using the "with" statement and
         take a RestRequest object as parameter.
        The point is to automate login and logout.
    """
    def __init__(self, restReq):
        self.restReq = restReq

    def __enter__(self):
        """ Enter : login() """
        self.restReq.login()
        return self.restReq

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        """ Exit : logout() """
        self.restReq.logout()


class RestRequest(RestRequestBase):
    """ class RestRequest. """
    def __init__(self, username, password, url_rest_base, endpoint, method, *args,
                 payload=None, outfile=None, file_mod=None):
        super().__init__(username, password, url_rest_base, endpoint, method, *args)
        self.method = method
        self.payload = payload
        self.outfile = outfile
        self.file_mod = file_mod
        self.response = None

def get_response(self):
    return self.response
```

Here is a part of the Flask app using this module :

```py
class CtrlmJobIdLogs(Resource):
    """ Control-M log on jobid """

    def get(self, jobid):
        """Get job's log."""
        rest_req = restRequest.RestRequest(USERNAME, PASSWORD, URL_REST_BASE, ENDPOINT_LOGS,
                                           'GET', jobid, payload=None, outfile=None,
                                           file_mod=None)

        with restRequest.RestRequestManager(rest_req) as req_man:
            req_man.perform()

        logging.debug('DEBUG>> : ctrlm_job --> {}'.format(jobid))
        return {jobid: req_man.get_response().json()}
```

Here is my test :

```py
class MockTests(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Test the rest module with mocks """
    ############################
    #### setup and teardown ####
    ############################

    def setUp(self):
        """ Executed prior to each test """
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        app.config['DEBUG'] = False

        self.client = app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        """ executed after each test """
        pass

    ###############
    #### tests ####
    ###############
    #@mock.patch('MonAPPflaskRest.flaskRest.restRequest.RestRequestManager')
    @mock.patch('MonAPPflaskRest.flaskRest.restRequest.RestRequest')
    def test_ctrlM_no_output(self,  mock_RestRequest):
        """ UAT 4 : ctrl-M job output is not found. """
        print("\n\n======================================")
        print("test_ctrlM_no_output")
        print("======================================")


        jobid_no_output = 'blabla:1epyx'
        message_noutput = 'Job CTRL-M {} not found'.format(jobid_no_output)
        expected_dict = { "blabla:1epyx": {"errors": [{ "message": "Request  rejected by Data Center CTM5319 OUTPUT DOES NOT EXIST FOR THIS JOB"}]} }

        # mock object :
        mock_response = mock.MagicMock()
        mock_response.json.return_value = expected_dict
        mock_response.status_code.return_value = 500

        # # the patched object returns values
        mock_RestRequest.response.return_value = mock_response
        #mock_RestRequest.return_value.response.return_value.json.return_value = expected_dict

        # REST url to test
        url = '/ctrlm/{}/output/'.format(jobid_no_output, follow_redirects=True)

        # call
        response_dict = self.client.get(url)
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882226/convert-test-client-data-to-json

        # assertions tests
        mock_RestRequest.assert_called()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Pytest ouptut is :

```
collected 1 item

tests\test_mock.py F

================================== FAILURES ===================================
_______________________ MockTests.test_ctrlM_no_output ________________________

self = <test_mock.MockTests testMethod=test_ctrlM_no_output>
mock_RestRequest = <MagicMock name='RestRequest' id='79830480'>

    @mock.patch('MonAPPflaskRest.flaskRest.restRequest.RestRequest')
    def test_ctrlM_no_output(self,  mock_RestRequest):
        """ UAT 4 : ctrl-M job output is not found. """
        print("\n\n======================================")
        print("test_ctrlM_no_output")
        print("======================================")



        jobid_no_output = 'blabla:1epyx'
        message_noutput = 'Job CTRL-M {} not found'.format(jobid_no_output)
        expected_dict = { "blabla:1epyx": {"errors": [{ "message": "Request  rejected by Data Center CTM5319 OUTPUT DOES NOT EXIST FOR THIS JOB"}]} }


        # mock object :
        mock_response = mock.MagicMock()
        mock_response.return_value.json = expected_dict
        mock_response.return_value.status_code = 500

        # # the patched object returns values
        # mock_RestRequest.get_response.return_value = mock_response

        mock_RestRequest.get_response.return_value.status_code.return_value = 500
        mock_RestRequest.get_response.return_value.json.return_value = expected_dict

        #mock_RestRequest.return_value.response.return_value.json.return_value = expected_dict
        print('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$', mock_RestRequest.mock_calls)
        print('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$', mock_RestRequest.get_response.return_value.status_code.return_value)



         # REST url to test
        url = '/ctrlm/{}/output/'.format(jobid_no_output, follow_redirects=True)

        # call
>       response_dict = self.client.get(url)

tests\test_mock.py:70:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py:791: in get
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask\testing.py:127: in open
    follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py:764: in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ, buffered=buffered)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py:677: in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py:884: in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py:1997: in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py:1985: in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py:273: in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py:1540: in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py:32: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py:1982: in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py:1614: in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py:273: in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py:1517: in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py:32: in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py:1612: in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py:1598: in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py:484: in wrapper
    return self.make_response(data, code, headers=headers)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py:513: in make_response
    resp = self.representations[mediatype](data, *args, **kwargs)
..\..\virtualenvs\tools\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\representations\json.py:21: in output_json
    dumped = dumps(data, **settings) + "\n"
c:\users\x165896\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\json\__init__.py:231: in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
c:\users\x165896\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\json\encoder.py:199: in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
c:\users\x165896\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\json\encoder.py:257: in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <json.encoder.JSONEncoder object at 0x036BC630>
o = <MagicMock name='RestRequest().get_response().status_code' id='81333936'>

    def default(self, o):
        """Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns
            a serializable object for ``o``, or calls the base implementation
            (to raise a ``TypeError``).

            For example, to support arbitrary iterators, you could
            implement default like this::

                def default(self, o):
                    try:
                        iterable = iter(o)
                    except TypeError:
                        pass
                    else:
                        return list(iterable)
                    # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
                    return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

            """
        raise TypeError("Object of type '%s' is not JSON serializable" %
>                       o.__class__.__name__)
E       TypeError: Object of type 'MagicMock' is not JSON serializable

c:\users\x165896\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\json\encoder.py:180: TypeError
```

I think, I got this because the mocked return values aren't used. Therefore, a mock object is created and of course cannot be use by the code...
in the pytest output :

```
o = <MagicMock name='RestRequest().get_response().status_code' id='81333936'>
```

So, this means i fail to mock the right thing.

What i really want to mock is the RestRequest instance variable : 'response'. Which is a Requests.response object.

I succeeded patching directly the 'MonAPPflaskRest.flaskRest.restRequest.RestRequest.response' variable. And output sounded good but assert_called() failed. So, giving me some doubt.

So, I don't really know what to mock, actually : the instance variable 'response', the object 'RestRequest', the context manager, ....

Comment: Is that all of the pytest output? What line in the test is causing the error?

Comment: @LuisOrduz  This line causes the problem  : response_dict = self.client.get(url)

Comment: When you do that call, you're actually just running the flask view function normally and doing what's supposed to be doing, but at that point you've mocked away RestRequest so flask is just running the request using the mock instead of your actual class.

Comment: I have edited and change the use of an object instance variable, but instead a method. That way, i'm trying to stick to what i see most of the time in stackoverflow.

Comment: @stockersky I think the best way is using `test_client` instead `mocking` of requests. Change mode of app before tests `app = flask.Flask(__name__) app.testing = True`. In tests: `with app.test_client() as client:
client.post(....) # or client.get(...)`. When a project has a lot of mocks is hard for debugging/understanding of correct behavior.